# How can i make Springboot application start daily and shutdownn after completing process in GCP

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-helm

i will be using helm charts to deploy my application in GCP.i want to make my springboot shutdown after completing its process and then on next day start on its own at a particular time -complete the process and shut down .Is this possible in GCP?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cloud Run Jobs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/create-jobs) or [Batches](https://cloud.google.com/batch/docs/get-started) to complete that and by paying ONLY when you process consume ressources. (Not the case with Kubernetes and GKE where you pay for your cluster (and your node pools) even if nothing runs on it)